# Read property of object as one of types

Tags: typescript, types, dynamic-typing

Type definitions for some objects are a little wonky. I know the properties and I know the type but the compiler doesn't. I want to write a small function that extracts the property with the type that I expect, but throws an error if the type is wrong.

So I want to know if the "readProperty" function below can somehow tell the compiler that e.g. **the extracted property is a number, because the developer wrote "number" when invoking the function**

Is this possible?

```
function readProperty<T>(obj: T, key: keyof T, typeName: "string" | "number"): string | number {
    const value = obj[key]
    if (typeof value != typeName) {
        throw new Error(`Property ${key.toString()} must be a ${typeName}`)
    }
    return value
}

const someObj = {
    x: "123",
    y: 123,
}

const x = readProperty(someObj, "x", "number") // <-- compiler should "know" now that x is a number
const y = readProperty(someObj, "y", "string") // <-- compiler should "know that y is a string
```

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wvakkm) what you're looking for? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use case I don't think there's much use for making the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of `obj` or the type of `key`.  If the compiler actually knew enough about `obj` and `key` for such a generic call signature to be useful, you wouldn't need to do any further checking of the property type (or worse, the compiler would disagree with you about the type).

Instead, the important part is to get the call signature so that when you pass a value of [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"string"` as `typeName` then the output of the function is of type `string`, and if you pass `"number"` then the output is of type `number`.  The most straightforward way to represent a mapping between a string literal input type and an arbitrary output type is to use an [object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types) like an `interface`, and then looking up the output property involves an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) on the input string literal.  Like this:

```
interface TypeofMap {
    string: string;
    number: number;
}

function readProperty<K extends keyof TypeofMap>(
    obj: object, key: PropertyKey, typeName: K
): TypeofMap[K] {
    const value = (obj as any)[key]
    if (typeof value != typeName) {
        throw new Error(`Property ${key.toString()} must be a ${typeName}`)
    }
    return value
}
```

So `readProperty()` is generic in `K`, the type of `typeName` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be one of [the keys of](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) the `TypeofMap` interface... so either `"string"` or `"number"`.  And then the return type of the function is `TypeofMap[K]`, the corresponding type `string` or `number`.

Note that the compiler cannot really verify that the *implementation* of `readProperty` conforms to the call signature.  So I have [asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that `obj` is of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) via `(obj as any)` to loosen the type checking inside the function body enough to prevent errors.  That means you need to be careful that the implementation does the right thing.  If you were to change, say, `(typeof value != typeName)` into `(typeof value == typeName)`, the compiler would not notice or complain.  So take care.

Anyway, let's see if it works from the caller's side:

```
const x = readProperty(someObj, "x", "number");
//    ^? const x: number
const y = readProperty(someObj, "y", "string");
//    ^? const y: string
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOED2MCycmyA3gFDKXIDOYUoA5gFw12MDcFVIArgLYAjaC16DonAL5kyMHiARhgOEMigQ4AEwAKUHNihh0AHgDSyCAA9IIDdWQBrCOjxosuAkQB8ACi6UcAgBWLAGBEAoANA5OLDp60IYmTlGG2ABycHwQLCZkAJQsGNh4hJgA2iYAuqR+yAjKtMgAbnAANjwoALzI3qHIcHZwIOh5ZY7olbXAMD2p7s1tHcgAhN1zGVl5NVQ7yGAAFroA7sggECcAolC6UN4ABnH6hsgAJCTjAHRgOADKbCAMbx5CTIPg8RpCfqvEjrTIQCR3PK1KQ7NRgHhQFQtdoQMhSMj1ECNag4LIAeSCyG65B2FhYACIAIwAJgAzPSIrV0CwWazOfjCY0LFTVOptLonuhvCTyUEovSLBzkPTREIoPS8pwAPRanYAPQA-ASGmBkOgRWpNI8ElKZRAKYF5eglfTaPQARrtbqqIbpGQgA)

Comment: Thanks again! I did end up using a generic in the type of obj, so that `key: keyof T` helps the developer (me) know what properties are allowed to request for (using the `key` arg).

Answer (score 0):

Someone already answered this but I wanted to share the actual code I ended up with. The difference is that I use a generic type for the `obj` argument. This enables the compiler (and the IDE) to know what values are ok to use for the `key` argument.

```
export interface IPropertyObject {
    number: number
    string: string
    boolean: boolean
}

export function readProperty<T, K extends keyof IPropertyObject>(
    obj: T,
    key: keyof T,
    typeName: K
): IPropertyObject[K] {
    const value = (obj as any)[key]
    if (typeof value != typeName) {
        throw new Error(`Property ${key.toString()} must be a ${typeName}`)
    }
    return value
}
```

```
const someObj = { x: 123 }

const x = readProperty(someObj, "x", "number");
//                               ^ x is a valid property key for the "someObj" object
```